# SVG div rotates on click but then does not rotate back on second click

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, onclick

So I literally only discovered last night that svg CSS animation was even possible so please excuse any daft mistakes I have made.
I am trying to make an SVG menu icon (the 3 bars) which when clicked, the top and bottom lines will rotate to form an X, and the middle line will fade out.

From the tutorials I have watched, it seems that CSS animation is written inside the SVG files itself. Here is what I have so far -

```
<svg id="menuicon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 160 160" >
<g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="6">

<style>
#menuicon.menuopen .topline{
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
         -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg); 
         -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
         -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 20 20;
  transition:0.8s;
}

#menuicon{
cursor:pointer;
}


</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
var clicker = document.querySelector('#menuicon');
clicker.addEventListener('click', function() {
this.classList.toggle('menuopen');

});
</script>

<path class="topline" d="m16.68 20.386l113.67.618"/>
<path class="midline" d="m16.06 52.819l109.96.618"/>
<path class="lowline" d="m15.14 92.05l108.11.927"/></g>
</svg>
```

A link to this file can be found - http://casb1.cloudapp.net/1016/1be61016ff9a717aa34c2adf7c5aa79e/icon%20test/menu%20icon.svg

As you can see (in chrome at least) is that the top bar will rotate when clicked, but then will not reverse its animation when clicked again.

I am doing this as a test to get my head around things so I am not looking for it to be all that refined (hence the sloppy vector paths).

Also it would be worth mentioning that my knowledge of JS is basically none at this point but I am ok with HTML and CSS.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `transition` property to `#menuicon .topline` instead of `#menuicon.menuopen .topline`.

In your code line jumps back because transitions applied to `#menuicon .topline` only when `menuopen` class presented on element so when you remove it (by `toggle()` method) no transition applied any more.

Comment: Spot on! This worked perfectly. If you don't mind explaining it though, why did this work? Is it because .menuopen defines the end position or is it something else?